# Using fluid mechanics to show that force is directly proportional to velocity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator

So I am writing a paper about viscous dampers in harmonic oscilators, however I was looking at some old fluid mechanic notes and I thought I had come across what I needed although I have gotten stuck. So I have that $\tau=\mu\frac{\delta u}{\delta y}$ this yields that $F=A*\mu\frac{\delta u}{\delta y}$. I want to get $F\propto\frac{\delta u}{\delta t}$ somehow but I am getting stuck, I'm not even sure its possible. Although I would like some guidance. Also this is assuming that we do not know that drag force is -$kmv$.

Comment: Do you mean $d \mathbf{p}/dt = \mathbf{F}$?  Or are you asking about the chain rule and how to use it to convert $\delta u/\delta y$ $\rightarrow$ $(\delta t/\delta y) (\delta u/\delta t)$?

Comment: Would using the chain rule show that F∝δu\δt ?

Comment: I think so, as long as $u \neq (\delta y/\delta t)$ and if I am understanding your question.

Comment: The drag force depends on the velocity in a non-trivial way. It is proportional at low velocities, becomes quadratic for turbulent flow and makes a strong jump for supersonic flow. Since drag means energy loss, fluid mechanics can only give that to you if you model the dispersion of energy in the fluid properly. Otherwise it's just forced on top with ad-hoc assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

At low Reynolds number, as in a creeping flow, one can ignore the advective acceleration terms in the Navier-Stokes equation. If we also assume a steady state, the equation becomes
\begin{equation}
0 = -\nabla p + \mu\nabla^2\vec{v},
\end{equation}
where $p$ is the hydrostatic pressure, $\mu$ is the viscosity of the fluid and $\vec{v}$ is the flow velocity.

Let us consider the motion of a small, spherical object in a fluid. An example could be motion of an oil droplet in Millikan's experiment. The moving object induces a flow in the fluid, which in turn, drags the object. If we solve this equation for a sphere of radius $R$, we first get the viscous force per unit area on the sphere to be 
\begin{equation}
\vec{f} = \frac{3\mu\vec{v}}{2R}
\end{equation}
We can then compute the drag force by integrating $\vec{f}$ over the entire surface. The result is 
\begin{equation}
\vec{F} = 6\pi\mu R\vec{v}
\end{equation}

Comment: Why does the specific gravity term drop? Is there a derivation that spells this out clearly? I referred to my book and it mentions this. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: The specific gravity term does not show up in the equation because the flow is not caused by gravity. It is induced by motion of a small sphere. The equation of motion of the sphere will have a term having gravity. In fact, the equality of the gravity term and drag force result in a uniform velocity of descent. Without the drag, the sphere would have accelerated as it falls.

Answer (score 0):

If you solve stokes flow (time-independent navier-stokes equation without the non-linear term) for a sphere, you will find a linear dependence between the drag and the velocity.